# Selenium-sendKeys() throwing 'Keys to send should be a not null CharSequence'

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, data-driven-tests

Hey guys i am new to Selenium and facing some issue .
There are 3 class , one is Data_Provider which reads data from excel another is a class to Add users (after reading from excel) last class is main class which calls Add class.

**Below is Add class code**

```
    package pomPagefactory;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class Add extends Data_Provider {
    public Add(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static String fname, lname, title, email, tel, uname, pass, cpass;

    @Test(dataProvider = "testset")
    public void create(String fname, String lname, String title, String email, String tel, String uname, String pass,
            String cpass) {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='FirstName']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='FirstName']")).sendKeys(fname);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='LastName']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='LastName']")).sendKeys(lname);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Title']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Title']")).sendKeys(title);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Email']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Email']")).sendKeys(email);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='TelephoneNumber']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='TelephoneNumber']")).sendKeys(tel);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='UserID']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='UserID']")).sendKeys(uname);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys(pass);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='cpassword']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='cpassword']")).sendKeys(cpass);

        driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']//span[@class='ng-scope'][contains(text(),'Create User')]")).click();

    }
}
```

The DataProvider class is correct no issue in it.

I have called Add class (methods in add class) in Main page(main class)

**Main class code**

```
  package pomPagefactory;
    //all imports;
    public class Admin {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void Page() throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\srawat\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        Locator loc = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Locator.class);
        loc.Login("uaadmin", "novell");

        loc.people_user();

        loc.create_new_user();
        Add ad=PageFactory.initElements(driver, Add.class);
        ad.create(Add.fname,Add.lname, Add.title, Add.email, Add.tel, Add.uname, 
        Add.pass, Add.cpass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the variables in `Add` class as static, and then you send them back to `create` method in `Add` class. It doesn't make much sense, and the source of the problem, the variables where never initialized so they are `null`.

In addition you misunderstood the use of `PageFactory`, `PageFactory.initElements` doesn't initialize `String` class variables, how can it know what value to put there? It initialize `WebElement` class variables with `@FindBy` annotation.

Delete the static variables from `Add` class, if you need them only in `create()` pass them to this method, if you need them in class level pass them in the constructor to `private` variables.

Comment: static variable are initialized with default values when  we create object for that class. default value for String class is null. so that it is coming as null.

Comment: @Murthi This is what I wrote *the variables where never initialized so they are `null`*